# Convert hex to alphanumeric (PHP)

Tags: php

Starting from a hex source, i want to convert it to `a-zA-Z0-9`.
base_convert() only supports as output a 32 base, that equals to `a-z0-9`. I need a base-62 output, for the additional `A-Z` (don't know how to better explain, sorry).

I'm doing this (since that the community often ask) cause of i'm using `openssl rand -hex` as a source for random password (i would love to use rand() and so on, but i need to have lots of unique passwords, and rand() or even mt_rand() doesn't provide enough casualty, password get repeated so often that the script locks down).

Thanks.

Comment: [Searching for „\[php\] base62“](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+base62) reveals several promising results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function base62_encode($hex)
{
    $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwvxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWVXYZ0123456789';
    $in = hexdec($hex);

    $result = '';

    while ($in > 0) {
        $i = $in % 62;
        $in = (int)($in / 62);

        $result = $chars[$i] . $result;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question, since I want to use it to be able to shorten 32 character hex UID numbers in URLs. Krzysztof's solution wouldn't work for me since converting the whole hex string into one 32bit or 64bit decimal integer will cause conversion to float and loses the extra entropy of the 128bit UID.
To fix Krzysztof's solution, I added a manual division by the base number that works directly on the hex string in a for loop, only using decimals for the small partial divisions:

```
function hex2setstring($hex)
{   
    $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwvxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWVXYZ0123456789';
    $setbase=strlen($chars);    

    $answer = '';   
    while (!empty($hex) && ($hex !== 0) && ($hex !== dechex(0))) {  

        $hex_result = '';
        $hex_remain = '';       

        // divide by base in hex:
        for ($i=0;$i<strlen($hex);$i+=1){

            $hex_remain = $hex_remain . $hex[$i];           
            $dec_remain = hexdec($hex_remain);
            // small partial divide in decimals:
            $dec_result = (int)($dec_remain/$setbase);          

            if (!empty($hex_result) || ($dec_result > 0))
                $hex_result = $hex_result . dechex($dec_result);

            $dec_remain = $dec_remain - $setbase*$dec_result;
            $hex_remain = dechex($dec_remain);
        }

        $answer = $chars[$dec_remain] . $answer;
        $hex = $hex_result;
    }

    return $answer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is

```
function hexToStr($hex)
{
    $s = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($hex)-1; $i += 2) {
        $s .= chr(hexdec($hex[$i] . $hex[$i + 1]));
    }
    return $s;
}
```

Comment: if i'm not wrong, chr() takes everything from ASCII, including =/*, that i don't want to. But maybe i'm wrong...

Comment: @cedivad hexdec() converts a hexadecimal string to a decimal number. Then, the input value of chr is "ever" in the range 0-9. chr() returns a one-character string containing the character specified by ascii.