# How to convert hex value to alphabetic string in php

Tags: php, string, hex

Is there way to get an alphabetical string for a specific hex value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert hex to alphanumeric (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551473/convert-hex-to-alphanumeric-php)

Comment: I want only alphabetic characters, There are digits also

Comment: What do you want to do with the non-alpha characters? Drop them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hex2bin` to convert hex:

```
$string = hex2bin($hex);
```

If you want to remove any non-alpha character from `$string` you can use a regular expression to remove anything that's not a-z or A-Z:

```
$alpha_only = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]+/", '', $string);
```